# How can I use getMinutes in this function instead of getHours

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set up a Livestream schedule app that automatically
changes css files and highlights the current running program every 30 minutes according to time of day.

Currently the function is working well. My problem is the function is in hours (getHours) which means the css file changes are hourly.

How can I change the function to work every half hour since the programs will only be 30mins long? I tried using getMinutes but no luck.

```
 // Program Schedule highlighter

function getStylesheet() {
  var currentHour = new Date().getHours();

  if (11 <= currentHour&&currentHour < 12) {
   document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='600.css' type='text/css'>");
  }
  if (12<= currentHour&&currentHour < 13) {
   document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='630.css' type='text/css'>");
  }
  if (13 <= currentHour&&currentHour < 14) {
   document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='700.css' type='text/css'>");
  }
  if (14 <= currentHour&&currentHour < 15) {
   document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='730.css' type='text/css'>");
  }
  if (15 <= currentHour&&currentHour < 16) {
   document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='800.css' type='text/css'>");
  }
  if (16 <= currentHour&&currentHour < 17) {
   document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='830.css' type='text/css'>");
  }

}

getStylesheet();
 </script>
</head>


  <h2 align="center">Line up</h2>

  <table align="center" width="80%" max-width="300px">
  <tr>
  <th>Time</th>
  <th>Program</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>6.00PM</td>
  <td>Maria Anders</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>7.00PM</td>
  <td>Francisco Chang</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>8.00PM</td>
  <td>Roland Mendel</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>9.00PM</td>
  <td>Helen Bennett</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>10.00PM</td>
  <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>11.00PM</td>
  <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>12.00AM</td>
  <td>Gio Roeli</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>1.00AM</td>
  <td>Chester Band</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>2.00AM</td>
  <td>Lionel Rolex</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>3.00AM</td>
  <td>Smith Weston</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>4.00AM</td>
  <td>Jasper Beaver</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>5.00AM</td>
  <td>Smiler Torres</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>6.00AM</td>
  <td>John Tobres</td>
  </tr>
  </table>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep it similar to your method you could use both `getMinutes()` and `getHours()` and add more conditions to the if statements.

```
function getStylesheet() {
  var date = new Date();
  var currentHour = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();

  // first set (first hour)
  if (11 <= currentHour && currentHour < 12 && minutes < 30) {
      document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='600.css' type='text/css'>");
  }
  else if (11 <= currentHour && currentHour < 12 && minutes >= 30) {
      document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='630.css' type='text/css'>");
  }

  // second hour
  if (12 <= currentHour && currentHour < 13 && minutes < 30) {
      document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='700.css' type='text/css'>");
  }
  else if (12 <= currentHour && currentHour < 13 && minutes >= 30) {
      document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='730.css' type='text/css'>");
  }
  // the rest of the conditions
  // ...
}
```

I've only included the first 2 sets of conditionals but hopefully you get the idea.

Or you could simplify it slightly:

```
  // first set (first hour)
  if (11 <= currentHour && currentHour < 12) {
      if (minutes < 30) {          
          document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='600.css' type='text/css'>");
      } else {
         document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='630.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
  }
  // etc...
```

Since `getHours()` returns an integer you only need to compare when it is equal to a certain value, so it could be simplified to something like:

```
  // first set (first hour)
  // midnight
  if (currentHour == 0) {
      if (minutes < 30) {          
          document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='000.css' type='text/css'>");
      } else {
         document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='030.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
  }
  // next
  if (currentHour == 1) {
      if (minutes < 30) {          
          document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='100.css' type='text/css'>");
      } else {
         document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='130.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
  }
  // etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make a config/schedule of the times you're after and give the stylesheet?

I didn't configure a full 24 hours, but you should get the point. If you don't plan on covering all 24 hours, I'd at least put in some sort of fallback stylesheet.

```js
const sheets = [
  { start: 1100, end: 1129 , sheet: 'one.css' },
  { start: 1130, end: 1159 , sheet: 'two.css' },
  { start: 1200, end: 1229 , sheet: 'three.css' },
  { start: 1230, end: 1259 , sheet: 'four.css' },
  { start: 1300, end: 1329 , sheet: 'five.css' },
  { start: 1330, end: 1359 , sheet: 'six.css' },
  { start: 1400, end: 1429 , sheet: 'seven.css' },
  { start: 1430, end: 1459 , sheet: 'eight.css' },
  { start: 1500, end: 1529 , sheet: 'nine.css' },
  { start: 1530, end: 1559 , sheet: 'ten.css' }
  
];
const getStyleSheet = () => {
  const date = new Date();
  const time = +`${date.getHours()}${date.getMinutes()}`;
  const sheet = sheets.find( s => s.start <= time && s.end >= time );
  return sheet ? sheet.sheet : 'outside of time range';
};

console.log(getStyleSheet());
```

One other suggestion is to use `setInterval` if the page is just sitting there and running for a long time. You can set that interval to 'tick' every 30 minutes and swap out the style sheet then. You would still need some sort of mapping for `time` to `style sheet`

Comment: Yes it will be 24/7. Hey thanks for that mwilson, much appreciated.  I'll give that a go.